# how to run the application straight away in ubuntu by hiding the os boot

Tags: qt

I done my application in qt, I want to boot it straight away in Ubuntu by hiding the OS boot I don't know to how to do it.Suggest me a solution.
i tried text mode in grub to hide the boot process. After that i don't know how to run the application.

Comment: What do you mean by hiding the os boot? What does your application do? I am asking because chances are that your application needs the ubuntu environment to run.

Comment: i dont want to see the os booting(purple screen), my applications will show the video.